# Swift Bridging Header for Obj-C

Tags: swift, swift2, cocoapods, bridging-header, cardio

I have installed `Card.IO` via `CocoaPods`. My workspace looks to be correctly setup, I see the `Card.IO` `Objective-C` header files in place however when, in my main `Swift` project, I try to reference any of the `Card.IO` classes - I get the unresolved identifier error.

**Edit**  My understanding is that `Xcode` cannot find the bridging header:

```
#import "CardIO.h"

@import AudioToolbox;
@import AVFoundation;
@import CoreMedia;
@import CoreVideo;
@import MobileCoreServices;
```

The documentation states

> In Build Settings, in Swift Compiler - Code Generation, make sure the Objective-C Bridging Header build setting under has a path to the
>   bridging header file.
>   The path should be relative to your project, similar to the way your Info.plist path is specified in Build Settings. In most cases,
>   you should not need to modify this setting.

This doesn't make sense to me - so not sure where to put the path? I've added the following to **Build Settings > Search Paths > Header Search Paths > Debug & Release**

```
MyApp/MyApp-Bridging-Header.h
```

but it seems this is incorrect?

Comment: Have you added .h files in bridging header?

Comment: I have copied the contents of their bridging header into a .h file. This only has imports of frameworks and doesn't resolve the issue. Also the steps on GitHub page just say to install via cocoa pods - no other steps needed.

Comment: 1: CocoaPods are different than normal xCode projects. (go through readme file of card-io) 2: You need to create your own bridging header and import .h files as in sample SampleApp-Swift. (Dont copy entire bridging-header file in your project. )

Comment: I have updated the question with the bridging header I added - still doesn't resolve

Comment: @SaqibOmer not always ;) just use use_frameworks!

Comment: @clicky do what @Daij-Djan says and add `use_frameworks!` to your `Podfile`, re-install, then you can use import statements `(FYI import NOT @import)` instead of using a bridging header file.

Comment: @sbarow I already have this in my Podfile...

Comment: @clicky build your project and see if the errors go away, sometimes before you build you will see errors when trying to import.

Comment: @sbarow no difference after building

Comment: if you have it in the pod, then don't add a bridging header and just import it

Comment: @Daij-Djan `import CardIO` does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here

https://bohemianpolymorph.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/manually-adding-a-swift-bridging-header/

> In your project build settings, find Swift Compiler – Code Generation, and next to Objective-C Bridging Header add the path to your bridging header file, from the project’s root folder. So it could by MyProject/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h or simply MyProject-Bridging-Header.h if the file lives in the project root folder.